# Spree 2 - Advanced Reporting - Rails 4 - Run Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, spree

Has anyone successfully tried to install [Advanced Reporting](https://github.com/stephskardal/spree-advanced-reporting) using Rails 4?

I've successfully installed Spree 2 and was able to get the initial site up and running without this gem. However, this gem throws an error while running `rails s`, in the development environmnet.

Error message received when: `rails s`

```
D:\work\projects\ror\clientsite.com\sites\deals.clientsite.com>rails s
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
D:/work/projects/ror/clientsite.com/sites/deals.clientsite.com/vendor/extensions/advanced_reporting/ruby/2.0.0/gems/ruport-util-0.14.0/lib/ruport/util/graph/amline.rb:105: warning: undefining `object_id' may cause serious problems
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.0.0 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
D:/work/projects/ror/clientsite.com/sites/deals.clientsite.com/vendor/extensions/advanced_reporting/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in `load': cannot load such file -- D:/work/projects/ror/clientsite.com/sites/deals.clientsite.com/vendor/extensions/advanced_reporting/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/spree_active_shipping-057d7d306cdc/lib/spree_active_shipping/../../app/models/spree/calculator/shipping/canada_post/priority_worldwide_intl.rb (LoadError)
    from D:/work/projects/ror/clientsite.com/sites/deals.clientsite.com/vendor/extensions/advanced_reporting/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in `block in load'
    from D:/work/projects/ror/clientsite.com/sites/deals.clientsite.com/vendor/extensions/advanced_reporting/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
    from D:/work/projects/ror/clientsite.com/sites/deals.clientsite.com/vendor/extensions/advanced_reporting/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in `load'
    from D:/work/projects/ror/clientsite.com/sites/deals.clientsite.com/vendor/extensions/advanced_reporting/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/spree_active_shipping-057d7d306cdc/lib/spree_active_shipping/engine.rb:32:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
    from D:/work/projects/ror/clientsite.com/sites/deals.clientsite.com/vendor/extensions/advanced_reporting/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/spree_active_shipping-057d7d306cdc/lib/spree_active_shipping/engine.rb:31:in `each'
    from D:/work/projects/ror/clientsite.com/sites/deals.clientsite.com/vendor/extensions/advanced_reporting/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/spree_active_shipping-057d7d306cdc/lib/spree_active_shipping/engine.rb:31:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    from D:/work/projects/ror/clientsite.com/sites/deals.clientsite.com/vendor/extensions/advanced_reporting/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from D:/work/projects/ror/clientsite.com/sites/deals.clientsite.com/vendor/extensions/advanced_reporting/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from D:/work/projects/ror/clientsite.com/sites/deals.clientsite.com/vendor/extensions/advanced_reporting/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from C:/ruby/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
    from C:/ruby/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from C:/ruby/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from C:/ruby/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from C:/ruby/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
    from C:/ruby/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from C:/ruby/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
    from D:/work/projects/ror/clientsite.com/sites/deals.clientsite.com/vendor/extensions/advanced_reporting/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from D:/work/projects/ror/clientsite.com/sites/deals.clientsite.com/vendor/extensions/advanced_reporting/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
    from D:/work/projects/ror/clientsite.com/sites/deals.clientsite.com/vendor/extensions/advanced_reporting/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from D:/work/projects/ror/clientsite.com/sites/deals.clientsite.com/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from D:/work/projects/ror/clientsite.com/sites/deals.clientsite.com/vendor/extensions/advanced_reporting/ruby/2.0.0/gems/polyglot-0.3.3/lib/polyglot.rb:63:in `require'
    from D:/work/projects/ror/clientsite.com/sites/deals.clientsite.com/vendor/extensions/advanced_reporting/ruby/2.0.0/gems/polyglot-0.3.3/lib/polyglot.rb:63:in `require'
    from D:/work/projects/ror/clientsite.com/sites/deals.clientsite.com/vendor/extensions/advanced_reporting/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
    from D:/work/projects/ror/clientsite.com/sites/deals.clientsite.com/vendor/extensions/advanced_reporting/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
    from D:/work/projects/ror/clientsite.com/sites/deals.clientsite.com/vendor/extensions/advanced_reporting/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
    from D:/work/projects/ror/clientsite.com/sites/deals.clientsite.com/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from D:/work/projects/ror/clientsite.com/sites/deals.clientsite.com/vendor/extensions/advanced_reporting/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    from D:/work/projects/ror/clientsite.com/sites/deals.clientsite.com/vendor/extensions/advanced_reporting/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from D:/work/projects/ror/clientsite.com/sites/deals.clientsite.com/config.ru:in `new'
    from D:/work/projects/ror/clientsite.com/sites/deals.clientsite.com/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from D:/work/projects/ror/clientsite.com/sites/deals.clientsite.com/vendor/extensions/advanced_reporting/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    from D:/work/projects/ror/clientsite.com/sites/deals.clientsite.com/vendor/extensions/advanced_reporting/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    from D:/work/projects/ror/clientsite.com/sites/deals.clientsite.com/vendor/extensions/advanced_reporting/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from D:/work/projects/ror/clientsite.com/sites/deals.clientsite.com/vendor/extensions/advanced_reporting/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from D:/work/projects/ror/clientsite.com/sites/deals.clientsite.com/vendor/extensions/advanced_reporting/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
    from D:/work/projects/ror/clientsite.com/sites/deals.clientsite.com/vendor/extensions/advanced_reporting/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:48:in `app'
    from D:/work/projects/ror/clientsite.com/sites/deals.clientsite.com/vendor/extensions/advanced_reporting/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
    from D:/work/projects/ror/clientsite.com/sites/deals.clientsite.com/vendor/extensions/advanced_reporting/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:75:in `start'
    from D:/work/projects/ror/clientsite.com/sites/deals.clientsite.com/vendor/extensions/advanced_reporting/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:78:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from D:/work/projects/ror/clientsite.com/sites/deals.clientsite.com/vendor/extensions/advanced_reporting/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `tap'
    from D:/work/projects/ror/clientsite.com/sites/deals.clientsite.com/vendor/extensions/advanced_reporting/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. It is failing to find the file `app/models/spree/calculator/shipping/canada_post/priority_worldwide_intl.rb`. Does it exists? If not, can you find it on the rails folder somewhere?

Comment: This project will not work with Spree 2.0 without significant modification.  Spree has changed a lot in the 3 years since this project was most recently updated and refers to tables and models which have since been renamed or which no longer exist.  There are some forks which have updated the project to at least Spree 1.3 that may get you further along.

Comment: @fotanus - Thank you. I looked and the file exists in the location of where it doesn't seem to find the file: `D:\work\projects\ror\snapsac.com\sites\deals.clientsite.com\vendor\extensions\advanced_reporting\ruby\2.0.0\bundler\gems\spree_active_shipping-057d7d306cdc\app\models\spree\calculator\shipping\canada_post\priority_worldwide_intl.rb`

Comment: It might be a permission problem if the path is correct.